# Is it possible to train a model to detect a shape?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection

We have multiple object detection APIs that can help us to find the bounding box coordinates.

But is it possible to go a little further and find/separate the shape of the object (say cat/dog/human) that we are looking for from the image?

What I need is just a mask that has white color where the object is and black color wherever it is not in the image.

Comment: I think the answer to 'is it possible' is clearly *yes*, but I presume you want to know a lot more than that. What sort of answer are you looking for? This might be a better fit for Stackoverflow if you're looking for details about code, applications, etc, but you'll probably need to explain in more detail what you're after.

Comment: First of all just wanted to know if this can be implemented or if we have any references or tutorials on this. And if yes then just brief steps like which model can be used, etc would be good enough for me to get started .

Comment: What you describe is called "image segmentation", possibly "instance segmentation" if you are interested in the shapes of all objects of some class in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear good things about Tensor Flow for applications such as this.  Here is someone's blog where they do something similar:
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tensorflow-object-detection-to-do-pixel-wise-classification-702bf2605182

They have helpfully provided their code on github here https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/Mask_RCNN/Mask_RCNN_Videos.ipynb

They first do 'instance segmentation' where they detect boundaries of an object, and they use 'FASTER R-CNN' (a convoluted neural network approach) to generate the mask.

Comment: That helps. Thanks a lot!